# Google Maps API to get location address as well as domain information

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

I am working with Google Maps Javascript API & using places library. Although I am able to get the location address but I also need to get the location domain information like suppose if the location is a business & also has a website URL linked to that location. Can someone guide me to the right API or library that also provides the Domain information of a location ? So far I have not come across any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `places` library to get other information as well

```
//make a request variable attaching the data you require , make sure to use only those which you require as detail request are billed separately
var request = {
  query: 'yourquery',
  fields: ['address_component', 'website']
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);

//Here you get the result 
function callback(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
   var website = place.website; // get the website, may be empty
   var type = place.address_component.types[0]; //this is an array and can be empty
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. After reading your reply I was also able to find the documentation regarding the requests we can make & the response we can get. Here is the documentation URL: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields

Seems like this will help me achieve what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your time mate.